# Silverlight application and Geometry Data

Tags: spatial-database, arcgis-silverlight-viewer

I have a table in SQL server 2012

`TABLE [Feature](
    [GUID] [unique identifier] NOT NULL,
    [Geom] [geometry] NOT NULL)`

in this table record my feature.

I need create an application with Silverlight that all of my feature show in application. Users need Edit (add, delete, update) features from the Silverlight application

I can show my feature data in grid-view. but still I can't find any component to show my feature data.

1. is Exist any component for show/add/delete feature?
2. how I can show list of feature in Silverlight application?

Comment: GIS SE has a "One question per Question" policy. Please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand how things work here. Since Microsoft has ceased new development on Silverlight, and newer browsers don't support it, choosing to start a new project using it seems to be quite limiting.. I'd recommend you  research GIS data presentation tools *before* choosing implementation details.